# Integrate :- $\int dx/(\sin(x) + a\sec(x))^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Please help me in evaluating this integral

$$
\int \frac{1}{(\sin(x) + a \sec(x))^2}\,dx
$$
I tried by converting $\sec(x)$ to $\cos(x)$ and by solving it became more complicated so guys please guide me further.

Comment: I have no idea how but take a look at it : [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5B1%2F(sin(x)%2Ba%2Fcos(x))%5E2%5D]

Comment: Have you tried Weierstrauss sub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$\dfrac1{(\sin x+a\sec x)^2}=\dfrac1{2(\sin x\cos x+a)^2}+\dfrac{\cos2x}{2(\sin x\cos x+a)^2}$$

The second part is elementary.

$$\dfrac1{(\sin x\cos x+a)^2}=\dfrac{\sec^2x(1+\tan^2x)}{(\tan x+a\tan^2x+a)^2}$$

Choose $\tan x=u$

Comment: I didn't get what You  did after saying elementary

Comment: @Ritik, Divided numerator & denominator by $$\cos^4x$$

Comment: Oh you did it very well thanks for answering 

Comment: For the second fraction, it is simpler to set $u=\sin2x$, so $du=2\cos2x$ and the integral becomes $\int\frac{1}{(u/2+a)^2}\,du$

Comment: @egreg, That's what I left for the OP !

Comment: How you guys are so good at integration ??

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't think that dividing by $\cos^4x$ is the best way.

Comment: What answer do you get?